# Live Ajax Search not printing all results

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a HTML page with a text box in which a user would type a country into, and then AJAX and PHP would query a mysql database of countries and print them in a DIV below. The code works just fine apart from one thing. If I type 'A' in the text box, it only prints one result on screen, 'Afghanistan', whereas it should be printing every country starting with 'A'. I imagine the fault lies with the response text, but how would I print out multiple responses, or does that even make sense :P Below is the relevant code.

The PHP database query

```
<?php
$country=$_REQUEST['country']; //get the country sent by Ajax
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","MYUSERNAME","MYPASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("countrydb", $connection);  
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE country LIKE '%$country%'",$connection);
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

echo $row['country'];
else
  echo "noresults";
mysql_close($connection); 
?>
```

This is the relevant javascript

```
    function showcountryStatus() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
              if (request.responseText == "noresults") {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML="No Results";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=request.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So basically my search is returning only the first result, whereas it should be returning a whole list. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you can read on the page about [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) you should use it in a loop, e.g.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['country'];
}
```

Now you're only fetching the first result.

Comment: You shouldn't just `echo` all the results one after another.
Consider adding the results to an array and then using `json_encode` on it. Of course, you will have to adapt the JavaScript side too.
  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php